# Looking for a good database plugins API

Tags: python, database

At my work, we are using different SQL and NOSQL database types (i.e postgres, mysql, sqlite, mongodb, arangodb).

As we are creating lots of packages communicating with a database to retrieve some data. Recreating the CRUD functionality (+ methods to create schema => create table/collection/db) for each package make it harder to maintain the whole pipeline while scaling up.

In order to solve this situation more easily, we decided to create a database plugins API that allows us to abstract CRUD methods so you don't care about the backend database being used anymore on the backend side. All packages that need to communicate with a database will just wrap the plugins CRUD methods and add their own package specific behaviour.

I'm pretty sure we are not the only having this kind of situation out there, so I 've been looking on the web to try to find if such a thing has already been done without finding anything interesting.

Could anyone refer me to anything that may do/try to do it?
Is there anything that already does it using Python?

Thanks

Comment: Probably you are looking for Django/Flask?

Comment: Unfortunately product recommendations are off topic on SO. sqlalchemy is known to abstract access to many SQL databases, and PyQt or PySide also have other abstraction. BTW the Python standard for SQL databases is the DB-API 2.0 specification described by PEP 249. By I must admit that I know no package with abstraction for SQL **and NOSQL** databases.

Comment: Thanks Serge,  actually I'm at the point of just trying to find anything that may do the job. I don't think there is any all in one solution. I was able to find Hibernate OGM  for NoSQL side but it doesn't cover all of the databases we are using. So far I think I'll have to use several solutions.